# Random Dataframe Column ordering

Tags: pandas, dataframe

strange question here but I was trying to create an empty dataframe with the following code.  I want the columns to be in the order that I wrote them but when output they are in a different order.  Is there a reason why this is happening intuitively?

```rb
import pandas as pd

user_df = pd.DataFrame(columns={'NAME',
                                'AGE',
                                'EMAIL',
                                'PASSWORD',
                                'FAVORITE_TEAM'
                               })
user_df
```

### Output:

```
PASSWORD    EMAIL   AGE NAME    FAVORITE_TEAM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is because use `set`s (`{}`), there is not defined order.

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects.

If use list (`[]`) all working nice:

```
user_df = pd.DataFrame(columns={'NAME',
                                'AGE',
                                'EMAIL',
                                'PASSWORD',
                                'FAVORITE_TEAM'
                               })
print (user_df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [AGE, FAVORITE_TEAM, EMAIL, NAME, PASSWORD]
Index: []
```

---

```
user_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['NAME',
                                'AGE',
                                'EMAIL',
                                'PASSWORD',
                                'FAVORITE_TEAM'
                               ])
print (user_df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [NAME, AGE, EMAIL, PASSWORD, FAVORITE_TEAM]
Index: []
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Why isn't it alphabetical at least?

Comment: @TheMattdavis17 - hmmm, hard question, but I guess because sets `{1,2}` and `{2,1}` are same (order is not important) in python

Comment: @TheMattdavis17 - Also I think another reason should be increse performance.

Comment: thanks @jezrael, this really helped and I like how quick you were to respond!